# Space colony equal socialism?

Tags: economy, space-colonization

So I have an idea that space colonies will be funded by corporations so they can get the planet's resources, much like with the new world colonies. But since the ones in charge are controlling all the resources and businesses, does that count as socialism? Could it lead to it?

Comment: It might. It might not. There's no way we can give you a good answer because you've given us no other information.

Comment: I mean did the US become a socialist state ?

Comment: Space colonies funded by corporations so they can get the planets resources? More likely funded corporations will simply take the planet's resources and forget the middleman in orbit.

Comment: When corporations control resources and populations, that is not socialism but a "corporate version of feudalism." How quickly would the population be reduced to "slavery" where they have to work "hours off the clock" or be on "salary" but needing to work 80 hours a week? When the corporation has the power such as in a space colony, that will happen quickly. See recent corporate takeovers for example.

Comment: You should define what you mean by socialism, or what particular flavor of socialism you are asking about. The dictionary definition is not everybody's definition and may not be your internalized definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think the question is pretty broad and is difficult to answer without more information, in real world politics, socialism is usually opposed to corporate control in theory. You may notice that socialist / Communist governments usually lead to dictatorships, but even in those cases that is generally opposed to the idea of top-down corporate control.

A more realistic scenario is that it would end up something like the Dutch East India company, with minority Rule and colonization, rather than a collective form of government.

Comment: Good idea with the Dutch East India trade company

Answer (score 0):

**Technically, No.**

So, as your resident Anti-Marxist, suffice to say, I'm hostile to the concept.

That said - the key tenant of Socialism is that **The workers own the means of production**

What this means is that there is no business owner, no management, everyone is equal in the company and receives the full value of their labour *In theory*.

Since the resources and business are owned by the Corporation (and not the workers) this is not Socialism.

You could say that this represents a form of Corporatism. You could possibly also say that this would represent a form of Fascism if the owners were a political entity "everything within the state nothing outside the state"

Now, you'll note I said **Technically, No** - because I'm referencing it against the book definition of Socialism. In terms of the practical realities of what happens when Socialism is implemented - it could absolutely be 'Socialism' - where everything is actually controlled by a small group of Elites - just makes sure you have the Kangaroo Courts, Gulags, Secret Police and brutal repression of everyone - and you could call it real-world 'Socialism'.